# Screen refresh rate disturbing wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, display, connection

I have a really weird problem: a few days ago I bought a new monitor, and everything works perfectly until I set its refresh rate to 144hz. Though I still detect WiFi, the PC can't connect to it. If I set refresh rate back to 60hz the issue disappears.

Is there a way to use the higher frequency and keep WiFi connectivity?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. More information about the monitor and your wifi device will be very helpful. Also, how close are the two devices to each other? Have you tried moving them farther apart?

Comment: It's quite possible the new screen you bought is badly engineered, and your mode with a refresh rate of 144 Hz has harmonics that interfere with Wifi. So either don't use this mode, or try to shield the screen somehow (e.g. experiment with aluminium foil) and/or move your antennas around.

Comment: You might search online for that issue with the particular model of monitor your purchased.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use the higher frequency and keep WiFi connectivity?

Beats me.

The technically correct answer will be equipment-dependent.  Some equipment is not designed to operate on such higher frequencies.  Software (such as your operating system) may still provide an option to use such a frequency, even if the hardware doesn't support it.  Trying to use an unsupported frequency can lead to improper operation, including damage to the monitor.  Other unpleasant effects, such as causing radiation that affects wireless communication, or even being a fire hazard that can destroy lots of equipment and your entire building, may be possible negative results.

Or, your monitor might be perfectly capable of supporting such resolutions.

CharlieRB provided an excellent suggestion in the comments.  At very minimum, finding out the model number of your monitor may be very helpful.  (To find your monitor's model number, your best bet may be checking the back of your monitor for a sticker/label or other writing.)  Until we have that, specific advice is likely unavailable, because the correct answer for one monitor may be advice that would be incorrect for another monitor.